# How does one enter a 'checkbox' character on a pdf generated by report4pdf?

Tags: pdf, checkbox, smalltalk, visualworks

So I am working on generating PDFs using the report4PDF package(bob nemec) from the VisualWorks 8.1 software from Cincom. I am doing everything in 'smalltalk'.

However right now, the issue I am facing is that I can't get a checkbox
character to show up on the PDF.

So my code would go along like this:

```
pdfDocument := Report4PDF.R4PReport new.
exporter := SAGETEAPDFDataExporter onDocument: pdfDocument.
exporter currentText text string:' Available'.
"Followed by relevant code to save PDF"
```

But what shows up on my PDF is basically ' Available'. A space appears instead of the checkbox symbol.  I even tried using dingbats codes(e.g: #9744 ). Works with the copyright, alpha, gamma symbols. Not with the checkbox symbol.

I tried updating my VisualWorks image from the public repository using the report4pdf, pdf development and fonts development packages. Ran into some 
issues which I wont mention since it will derail us from the topic.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What's the codePoint of the character you are trying to print? Also is that character visible when you use the same font your pdf uses?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia 
Apologies for the previous blank comment.
So what do you mean by 'codePoint'? I am not familiar with that term. Also for the second part, I can see the checkbox symbol when I 'inspect' the string in the debugger....  I use the Helvetica font which I think is the default font. Do you think that the font may not support the checkbox character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... So I ended up finding a solution to this question. I will just
post the answer here just in case anyone else gets in a similar situation.

```
    pdfDocument := Report4PDF.R4PReport new.
    exporter := SAGETEAPDFDataExporter onDocument: pdfDocument.
    exporter currentText text:[:text|
         text string zapfDingbats ;string:'q'. 
         text string helvetica; string:'Available' ].
```

So you can use dingbats font to get a similar character for checkbox. You use 
mixed fonts to get something like this:' (Checkbox) Available'.
So that's like the string is: 'q Available'. But 'q' is of the dingbats font while the 'Available' substring is of Helvetica.

Hope that helped. And thank you again @Leandro for trying to help me :)

Cheers!

Comment: Nicely solved. You may also want to look at R4PBullet, which allows for a text line with a bullet using any font. See R4PReportTest>>exampleBullet

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I tried looking at the R4Bullet section but could not find a suitable type of bullet point. They were all solid blacks whereas I need something like a blank checkbox. 

And btw great job on the Report4PDF Package. Its really useful. :)